# Wordpress & JWPlayer plugin - adding video thumbnail to loop

Tags: wordpress, jwplayer

I have a Wordpress site with the JWPlayer plugin installed.

I embed a video into a Post and then have an archive page for that post type.

Is there a way I can display the video thumbnail on the archive page? Each Post will only ever have one video embedded in it.

I've seen forum articles mentioning *wp_get_attachment_metadata* and *jwplayermodule_thumbnail* etc but my knowledge of what's possible with these is still limited.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: We don't have anything that does this out of the box, but I can certainly ask the developer of the WP plugin about this.